# gitlab CI: access github repositories via SSH?

Tags: github, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I need to use some repositories from github on a hosted gitlab server. I will need to use both public and private ones.

1. First I created bot user on github, to act as a proxy.
2. Then I created `id_ed25519` private/public key pair.
3. Added public key on github bot user.
4. When Gitlab CI runs, same public/private key is added for root user.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
---
image: my-img

stages:
  - build

before_script:
  # Set up access to be able to use some github repositories.
  - mkdir -p /root/.ssh
  - chmod 700 /root/.ssh
  - touch /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
  - chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
  - touch /root/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
  - chmod 644 /root/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
  # -e to recognize multiple lines
  - echo -e $BOT_PRIVATE_KEY > /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
  - echo $BOT_PUBLIC_KEY > /root/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    # NOTE. This is a public repo!
    - git clone git@github.com:odoo/odoo.git
```

Here what `gitlab-ci` pipeline outputs:

```
$ mkdir -p /root/.ssh
$ chmod 700 /root/.ssh
$ touch /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
$ chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
$ touch /root/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
$ chmod 644 /root/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
$ echo -e $BOT_PRIVATE_KEY > /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
$ echo $BOT_PUBLIC_KEY > /root/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
$ git clone git@github.com:odoo/odoo.git
Cloning into 'odoo'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: have you verified that you can do a git clone manually with this ssh key set up?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle yes, if I create new local user and add same key manually, it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was, that `github.com` was not added to `knowns_hosts`. Even though the error reported was misleading (as it is usually followed after you confirm host, but do not have access to repository).

Adding this to `before_script`, solves it:

`- ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: Nice find, glad you got it resolved and updated with an answer. out of curiosity when you down your manual test did you have to add the host

Comment: Yes, but it would show a prompt to accept a host. In gitlab CI, I did not show anything about that, so it mislead me.